# create-react-app yarn build is shipping my source codes into build directory

Tags: build, create-react-app, yarnpkg, production

It seems that when I run *yarn build* on the project created by *create-react-app* the *chunk.js* files will contain my original source and one can simply look at my code logic in pretty format in chrome's devtools. Am I missing something? For example look at this test website I have: https://alisalimi25.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

Following [this documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration), you should create a file named '.env' at root location, after that add "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false" to this file.

Hope it useful to you!